# Is there a GRPC error code equivalent for: 423 Locked?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, envoyproxy

On my http/grpc transcoded API I'm trying to return a 423 error under some given circumstances, but haven't found a rpc.Code to match the 423 error.

The closes I can think about would be: PERMISSION_DENIED(7), which returns a 403 error code, not the 423 that I would like to get back.

Any idea how I can overcome this limitation?

I'm using envoy.grpc_json_transcoder.

Thanks

Comment: How are you transcoding? grpc-gateway? Any answer will probably be specific to the transcoding tool.

Comment: @EricAnderson I'm using envoy.grpc_json_transcoder